# Debugging after computer rename

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, windows-7, visual-studio-2013

I renamed my computer in Control Panel, then restarted it to complete changes.
When I tried to debug my ASP.NET application - I've got popup with message: **'Unable to start debugging on the web server. The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. THe debugger was unable to resolve the specified computer name'**

Project set up to use local IIS, and http://shop.site.local, everything was good before computer renaming.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: Sounds like for the used web server to connect to it is defined as "computername". Isn't there an option to set it to 127.0.0.1 or am I mistaken there? (more used to desktop applications than web applications with VS)

Comment: @Thomas I searched in Debug/Options and Settings and didn't found any place. Probably computer name setup at visual studio  installtion time.

Comment: In my own experience with this error it turned out I had forgotten to add a local DNS mapping to the site in hosts. Once this was done, the problem went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the problem because of renaming.

**But Have you tried by renaming back to the old Name of your computer? Did that worked?**

**You can configure your project in IIS once again.**

Before doing that remove the `Current Configuration of your project` from `IIS`. And Create New Config for project.

**Or**

Create virtual Directory with some other name.

Try the above things, it should work. If `everything was good before computer renaming`.

[Reset Your IIS](https://support.gearhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200341925-How-to-reset-IIS-with-the-IIS-Reset-command) and `Restart Visual studio`. Try restart your computer if you renamed.

Read this Official Article completely. - [Error: Unable to Start Debugging on the Web Server.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx)

Comment: I can't debug even when back to old computer name.

Comment: But before the whole renaming the debugging functioned completely normally?

Comment: @Thomas, yes, all work properly before that. Don't want to reinstall VS, but it is last chance.

Comment: Have you did reset and restarts properly? So i guess there is no problem with name change. Other wise you can Try re-install the IIS from Windows Features.

Comment: @RJK yes, problem was in uninstall VS component. Cheers!